# How do I query my players and return them order of score?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following:

```
PUT players
{
  "mappings": {
    "player": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT players/player/1
{
  "name": "Dave"
}
PUT players/player/2
{
  "name": "Dan"
}
PUT players/player/3
{
  "name": "Macey"
}



PUT score
{
  "mappings": {
    "score": {
      "properties": {
        "player": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "score": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT score/score/1
{
  "player": "3",
  "action": "10"
}
PUT score/score/2
{
  "player": "2",
  "action": "5"
}
PUT score/score/3
{
  "player": "3",
  "action": "10"
}
PUT score/score/4
{
  "player": "2",
  "action": "7"
}
PUT score/score/5
{
  "player": "1",
  "action": "1"
}
PUT score/score/6
{
  "player": "1",
  "action": "2"
}
PUT score/score/7
{
  "player": "1",
  "action": "2"
}
PUT score/score/8
{
  "player": "1",
  "action": "1"
}
PUT score/score/9
{
  "player": "1",
  "action": "8"
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing. I need to sort my players by their total score (in descending order). So, if I query for "Da" I would like to get:

```
1. Dave - 14
2. Dan - 12
```

So far, I have:

```
GET /players/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "name": "Da"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I know it isn't right. I come mainly from an SQL world and am having a tough time figuring out how to join the tables and ordering on a count of a field. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: You should be better if you do not normalize your data, and then you can use **sort** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase the documentation on [handling relationships](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html), Elasticsearch documents live in isolation, there's no way to set up a simple relationship between documents.

To solve this quandary, one of the simplest solutions is to denormalize your data<sup>1</sup>, store your players data (probably trimmed to what you need to get your searches working) in your `score` documents and work on on that index.

For example, you could define your `score` index as

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "score": {
            "properties": {
                "player": {
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "nom": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "score": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would fill it with

```
PUT score/score/1
{
  "player": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Macey"
  },
  "score": "10"
}
PUT score/score/2
{
  "player": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Dan"
  },
  "score": "5"
}
PUT score/score/3
{
  "player": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Macey"
  },
  "score": "10"
}
```

Note that I replaced `action` keys by `score`.

Assuming you want a prefix query on the name (that's why `player.name` is `not_analyzed`), your query would look like

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "prefix": {
                "player.name": "da"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, to get the top score for each player, you would use aggregations:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "prefix": {
                    "player.name": "da"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "aggs" : {
        "players" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "player.id" ,
                "order" : { "maxvalue" : "desc" }
            },

            "aggs" : {
                "maxvalue": { "max" : { "field" : "score" } },
                "maxscore": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "score": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The top level agg defines buckets by player id, sorts them by the `maxvalue` sub aggregation and then extracts the top score by a `top_hits` aggregation.

Results are a bit verbose in Elasticsearch, you would get something like that (minus the query results)

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "players" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "maxscore" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 2,
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "xxxx:scores:1487236388",
                  "_type" : "score",
                  "_id" : "AVpGMlb1XRLwiv8C2uL2",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "player" : {
                      "id" : 2,
                      "name" : "Dan"
                    },
                    "score" : 12
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    12
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "maxscore" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 1,
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "xxxx:scores:1487236388",
                  "_type" : "score",
                  "_id" : "AVpGMlb1XRLwiv8C2uL3",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "player" : {
                      "id" : 1,
                      "name" : "Dave"
                    },
                    "score" : 14
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    14
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

<sup>1</sup> I know it's a bad word in SQL world, but you get used to it.

Comment: aggregations as altogether has different uses and certainly not for scoring the documents. you can refer my answer for to use function_score to sort parent documents based on child documents

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize child-parent relationship to support your data. You can probably create player profiles as parent documents and their score as child documents. Here is the link to [parent-child relationship document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html).

I have created mappings for you to support parent child relation ships

```
    PUT testindex12
    {
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {}
        },
        "mappings": {
            "player": {
                "properties": {
                    "players": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "score": {
                "_parent": {
                    "type": "player"
                },
                "_routing": {
                    "required": true
                },
                "properties": {
                    "player": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "score": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For more info on mapping parent-child check [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child-mapping.html).

Index the parent and child documents.

```
POST testindex12/player/1
{
  "player" : "sachin"
}

POST testindex12/player/2
{
  "player" : "rahul"
}

POST testindex12/player/3
{
  "player" : "virat"
}


POST testindex12/score?parent=3
{
  "score": 789
}
```

For more on indexing parent-child documents please refer [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/indexing-parent-child.html).

Following is the query where i am simply doing the filter on name, again here i want to point this to you as you are trying to do partial search on the name of the player, so you can use prefix search on name. Here is the documentation for [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-prefix-query.html). To score the documents based on score i have used function score. You can find more info about them [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

```
POST testindex12/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {

            "must": [
              { "prefix": {
                "player": {
                  "value": "sa"
                }
              }
                },{
                "has_child": {
                    "type": "score",
                    "score_mode": "sum",
                    "query": {
                        "function_score": {
                            "query": {
                                "match_all": {}
                            },
                            "score_mode": "sum",
                            "boost_mode": "sum",
                            "script_score": {
                                "script": "_score + doc['score'].value"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I will refrain you from doing the other solution by nikoshr as aggregations as altogether has different uses and certainly not for scoring the documents.

Hope this helps.
Thanks